# Trouble accessing a googlesheet using API created by someone else and only shared to specific persons

Tags: javascript, browser, google-sheets-api

Our supplier maintains a Googlesheet and we are trying to add a form on our website that accesses that sheet and pulls data from it. Very simple task but we are having trouble with OAuth. The sheet is not public and only shared with certain people (including my Google ID).

Now, I used Google Developer Console to setup the Googlesheets API library. I added a simple form which is here: https://alcocovers.com/knowledge-base/track-your-order/. When I first used the form, I clicked on the "sign in" button (currently hidden), it showed me the consent form in a popup, I signed in using my Google ID and it asked "alcocovers.com wants access to my profile info" and I gave access. The form started to work and I could pull information from the sheet and show on our web page.

But the problem is, the authentication I did to link the website to access my Google account (and the google sheet) doesn't work for everyone. If I use the form in incognito mode, it fails to access the sheet that means everyone who uses the form has to give consent. That doesn't make sense because I thought when I signed in first time and gave the website access to my account and sheet, it will work for everyone. It's the website making the access not the individual user. We want the users of our site to be able to use the form and pull data from the sheet. How can I achieve this?

Below is the code I am using to initialize and authenticate the client. This code is copy pasted from the Google Sheet API documentation. I am assuming this needs to change so the OAuth only happens once which is already done linking the site to the sheet and on future form use, no consent should be needed.

```
function initClient() {
    var API_KEY = '';  // I added api key here

    var CLIENT_ID = ''; // I added client id here  

    var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly';

    gapi.client.init({
        'apiKey': API_KEY,
        'clientId': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPE,
        'discoveryDocs': ['https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4'],
    }).then(function() {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSignInStatus);
        updateSignInStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
    });
}


function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
}

function updateSignInStatus(isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
        makeApiCall();
    }
}

function handleSignInClick(event) {
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
}

function handleSignOutClick(event) {
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
}
```

**Update #1:**
After trying the solution suggested by @Jescanellas, I am getting following error. Note, I kept the same API key, only changed the CLIENT ID.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The other users cannot use your credentials to access the Sheet. In order to do that you need to use a [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts). Once you create it you can use your Google Account to make the authorized calls to the API with [Domain-Wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#create_the_service_account_and_credential), by using the Service Account credentials instead of yours. Follow the steps from the documentation:

**1 - Create the service account and credentials**

> 1. Open the [Service accounts page](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts). If prompted, select a project.
> 2. Click add Create Service Account, enter a name and description for
>      the service account. You can use the default service account ID, or
>      choose a different, unique one. When done click Create.
> 3. The Service account permissions (optional) section that follows is
>      not required. Click Continue.
> 4. On the Grant users access to this service account screen, scroll
>      down to the Create key section. Click add Create key.
> 5. In the side panel that appears, select the format for your key: JSON
>      is recommended.
> 6. Click Create. Your new public/private key pair is generated and
>      downloaded to your machine; it serves as the only copy of this key.
>      For information on how to store it securely, see [Managing service
>      account keys](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#managing_service_account_keys).
> 7. Click Close on the Private key saved to your computer dialog, then
>      click Done to return to the table of your service accounts.

**2 - To enable G Suite domain-wide delegation:**

> 1. Locate the newly-created service account in the table. Under
>      Actions, click show more, then Edit.
> 2. In the service account details, click Show domain-wide
>      delegation, then ensure the Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation
>      checkbox is checked.
> 3. If you haven't yet configured your app's OAuth consent screen, you
>      must do so before you can enable domain-wide delegation. Follow the
>      on-screen instructions to configure the OAuth consent screen, then
>      repeat the above steps and re-check the checkbox.
> 4. Click Save to update the service account, and return to the table of
>      service accounts. A new column, Domain-wide delegation, can be seen.
>      Click View Client ID, to obtain and make a note of the client ID.

As said before, use the Service Account credentials to access the Sheet.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. Let me follow your guide. I will update and accept once everything is done. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: I have a question: is there an example to use Service Account credentials to access the Sheet using JavaScript? I am unable to find it. From what I am seeing on different pages, service accounts are not compatible with javascript due to security issues. If I have to use a service account, I need to use php or nodejs. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not aware of any security issue regarding Javascript and Service Accounts. You should be able to use it with your code by just changing the old credentials file to the SA one.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, I just updated my question with the error I am seeing in the browser console. Any ideas? Could this be because I don't have an @alcocovers.com G-Suite account added anywhere on this project? And even though enabled, "2 - To enable G Suite domain-wide delegation:" isn't actually working?

Comment: Try adding your domain to [Javascript origins](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#creatingcred) authorization. To do that, create a Web Application type ClientId and set it there. If that doesn't work, we can continue the conversation in a chat room to not extend the comments.

Comment: Thank you, let me try that and contact you on chat if that doesn't work.

Comment: Example using Node.js application on the server side: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59374303/google-sheets-api-minimal-example/59551025#59551025