# Google sheets API minimal example

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am using the [google-spreadsheet npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet) to fetch data from the first 2 tabs of a Google Sheet which has been shared with a service account. Since this is a simple task, I would like to remove the dependency on a third party package and use Google's libraries directly. However, there are many different Google libraries and I am not sure what to use.

Below is the google-spreadsheet based code I am currently using. How can I convert this to directly use Google libraries?

```
var GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
var creds = require('./credentials.json');

var doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('### spreadsheet id ###');

doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds, function(err) {
    doc.getRows(1, function(err, rows) {
        console.log(rows);
    });
    doc.getRows(2, function(err, rows) {
        console.log(rows);
    });
});
```

Comment: You mean [the official node.js library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)? Their [quickstart.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/sheets/quickstart.js) logs in and fetches data from a sheet. Or at least that's the first Google library I found - which are the many other different Google libraries you're chosing between?

Answer (score 1):

[This is](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) Google's officially supported Node.js client library for accessing Google APIs. This covers all types of authentication, including using a Service Account. I assume this is what you're looking for.

Also, in Google Sheets API [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) you can find many examples of this library in use.

On one side, there is [a quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) in which it is explained, step by step, how to set your application to make a call (in the example, it gets the values from a specified range in a spreadsheet, which, if I understood correctly, is what you want to do).

On the other side, you can find examples of this library in use for most of this API methods [in the reference tab](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest).

I hope this is of any help.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works with Google's library `googleapis` refereed in Google's "Node.js Quickstart" (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs).

You can install the client library with `npm install googleapis --save`

Google Sheets API reference (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest)

---

You could start with something like this:

```js
const { google } = require('googleapis');

const creds = require('./credentials.json');

// ID of the Google Sheets spreadsheet to retrieve data from
const spreadsheetId = '### spreadsheet id ###';

// Name of the sheet tab
const sheetName = 'Sheet1';

const authClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    creds.client_email,
    null,
    creds.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']);

const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: authClient });

sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet({
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
    // A1 notation of the values to retrieve  
    ranges: [sheetName + '!A:Z'],
    majorDimension: 'ROWS'
})
    .then((resp) => {
        const rangesOfValues = resp.data.valueRanges;
        rangesOfValues.forEach((range) => {
            console.log(range);
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });


// authClient.authorize()
//     .then(() => {
//         console.log("Authorize test passed...");
//     })
//     .catch((err) => {
//         console.log(err);
//     });
```

---

Let me know if that helps at all.